# Receiving string as parameter is terminated after whitespace

Tags: jsp

```
Enumeration e = session.getAttributeNames();  
    {
   while(e.hasMoreElements())
   {
       %>
        <tr>
            <%
       book = (String)e.nextElement();

       if(book.equals("userid"))
       {
       continue;
       }

       String book_price = (String)session.getAttribute(book);
           price_cast = Integer.parseInt(book_price);
          %>
       .                
       .
       .
       .

<td><input type="hidden" name="book_name" value=<%=book %> />

<td class="iron"><input type="submit" value="Update" /></td>

<% String str1 = request.getParameter("book_name");
               out.println(str1);
            %>
```

Suppose if the value of book is "Stalked by Spirits". Then receiving it in book_name, the output is only "Stalked" instead by "Stalked by Spirits". Please help me out.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `value="<%=book %>"` ?

Comment: I always say … “Kids, please learn HTML Basics, before you start Programming to generate HTML dynamically” … oh why dem never listens.

Comment: Thanks.......it should be this way......

Answer (score 0):

As The New Idiot points out, because of the missing quotes, you get just the first part of the string and that's actually the browser doing you a favor... :) Without the quotes it doesn't know where  the value ends, thus chaos wins!!! Also, you're missing the closing `<\td>` for your 1st `<td>`